# '[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Tags: swift, for-loop

I am looping through all contacted physics bodies for a game, but am getting this strange error with AnyObject. 

`var bodies = island1.island.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies()
 for body : AnyObject? in bodies {        }`

Comment: Not enough information. Explain what your methods actually do and what kind of objects you expect in your `bodies` array.

Comment: You seem unfamiliar with SpriteKit so I will fill you in. It returns all the "SKPhysicsBody" objects that are touching that physics body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bodies` here is an optional.  You've gotta unwrap it before you can iterate it.

```
if let bodies = island1.island.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies() {
    for body in bodies {
        // etc
    }
} else {
    println("There were no bodies")
}
```